# Is it possible to increase the Hastings ratio by combining and mixing elementary kernels?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, mcmc-acceptance-rate

Let's say I am working with a state $X$ split into three parts $U$, $V$, and $W$.

I can efficiently sample from $W|U,V$, $U|V$, and $V|U$. My initial intuition was to do a variable-at-a-time Metropolis Hastings algorithm to sample $X$.

However, I then realized that the candidate density defined by the following mixture:
$f(x^*|x) = f(w^*|u^*,v^*) \cdot (f(u^*|v^*) \cdot f(v^*|u) + f(v^*|u^*) \cdot f(u^*|v))/2$ produces an algorithm with acceptance ratio equal to one.

Is this part of some more general result? It looks like what I have is a Gibbs sampler, block sampling $U,V$ then $W|U,V$, but it only seems to work if I randomize the order in which I sample $U$ and $V$.

Is this indeed more efficient than using a variable-at-a-time sampler with acceptance ratios less than one?